# how to add a none globe ctrl hotkey with delphi

Tags: delphi

I got code from this site to set up a hotkey but when program is running it removes the options to copy and paste as ctrl is used in hotkey is there away to have it so the hotkey code only works within my program when window is select?

```
RegisterHotKey(Handle, 0, MOD_CONTROL, VK_INSERT);
```

thanks

Comment: RegisterHotKey registers a global hot key. If you want something specific to your program, use a shortcut.

Comment: any shortcut demos knocking around?

Comment: You know, add an action list, add an action, assign a shortcut

Comment: ok thanks sorted that but now I got a other question if you dont mind I want to be able to hold the insert down to do the command but currently if I hold down keep it will recall feature over and over is there any way to fix that?

Comment: I don't understand that at all. Sorry.

Comment: Ok am pressing Insert to call a voice chat command but I want to be able to press and hold the insert key down to keep the voice transmitting but soon as I un-press key it will stop sending data but currently its jumping from on to off when am holding down button

Comment: Then a shortcut is not what you want. You want to listen for `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp` events.

Comment: ya I want a hotkey for talk button so there dont need to press and hold button with mouse

Comment: so use OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp

Comment: ok I did that but for some reason it dont work press the keys and it dont do anything

Comment: if (key = ord('45')) then ShowMessage('Insert will turn off lock mic!');
    //hpTalkBtnClick(Sender);
  if (key = ord('17')) AND (key = ord('45')) then ShowMessage('Ctrl + Insert will turn off lock mic!');
    //hpTalkBtnClick(Sender);

Comment: Showing a dialog isn't going to be any use. That's going to take the input. Quite what `ord('45')` is I've no idea. You need to get on top of the basics. This is not the way to learn them.

Comment: ya this is taxing my brain lol

Comment: `'45'` is a string, and calling `Ord()` on a string makes no sense. `Key` in the `OnKeyDown/Up` events contains the *numeric* value of a **virtual key code**. You need to compare `Key` to a number, not a string.  Use `if (Key = 45) then`, or better, use the constant that is defined for the virtual key code of the Insert key: `if (Key = VK_INSERT) then`